# lerna ERR! lifecycle "preinstall" errored in "xyz-ui" in Angular Project

Tags: angularjs, npm, d3.js, lerna

I am getting this error on Jenkins build : lerna ERR! lifecycle "preinstall" errored in "xyz-ui", exiting 1 . I am using npx npm-force-resolutions in "preinstall" script in package.json.

"scripts": {
"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
....
....
}

"resolutions": {
"d3-color": "3.1.0"
}

I was trying to upgrade d3-color to version 3.1.0 in "resolutions" in package.json as d3-color version 2.0.0 which was being used internally by angular-d3-cloud (version 1.1.2) was giving whitesource vulnerability for my project. How to resolve it?